# How to find the oldest record stored in a table in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in a table with dates like 2017-04-13, 2018-05-15. How can we find the oldest record using a SQL query?

Comment: Select top 1 * from tablename order by datecolumn

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `top` clause that SQL Server has:

```
select top 1 *
from   yourTable
order by dateColumn asc
```

This way only the first row is returned and, combined with the ordering provided, that row will be the oldest one

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE  WHERE YOURDATEFIELD = (SELECT MIN(YOURDATEFIELD) FROM YOURTABLE)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select top 1 * from table order by {nameofcolumn} Asc
```

Answer (score 1):

select **top** 1 * from **tablename**
order by **columnname** desc